# add titles to ggplot2 plot as titles are showed in facet_wrap plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

It's posible to add titles to a single plot, like:

```
library(ggplot2)
gdURL <- "http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~jenny/notOcto/STAT545A/examples/gapminder/data/gapminderDataFiveYear.txt"
gDat <- read.delim(file = gdURL)
jDat <- droplevels(subset(gDat, continent != "Oceania"))
str(jDat)

jYear <- 2007
q <- ggplot(subset(jDat, year == jYear),
            aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp)) + scale_x_log10()
q + geom_point()

q + geom_point(aes(size = sqrt(pop/pi)), pch = 21)
```

[image]

As titles are showed (In a grey box and integrated with the plot) in a facet_wrap plot like this??:

```
r <- q +
   geom_point(aes(size = sqrt(pop/pi)), pch = 21, show_guide = FALSE) +
   scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,40))

r <- r + facet_wrap(~ continent)
r + aes(fill = continent)
```

[image]

Comment: You could add an extra column to your data set to be the faceting column and just have it contain only one category.

Comment: Maybe you can better formulate your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @jraab comment, one way to accomplish this is add a dummy column and use `facet_grid`:

```
jDat$dummy <- NA

ggplot(subset(jDat, year == jYear), aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ dummy)
```

If you want to manipulate the title, you could use:

`facet_grid(. ~ dummy, labeller=label_bquote("My New Title"))`

[image: Plot]